# Making an unfilled circle including a number in a table

Tags: tables, listings, highlighting, circles

I wonder is it possible to highlight a number enclosing with an unfilled circle next to a line in a listing or table like the image below?

```
\documentclass[english,a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{changepage}

\begin{document}

\clearpage
\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{adjustwidth}{-3.7cm}{}
\begin{tabular}{|p{.6\textwidth}|p{.75\textwidth}|}
\hline
{\begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle={\scriptsize\ttfamily},
identifierstyle={\color{black}},
tabsize=2,language={Java},
numbersep=18pt,numbers=left,xleftmargin=1.2cm,frame=tlbr,framesep=2pt,framerule=0pt,
morekeywords={class,run}]
class PrintHelloThread ext Thread {
    void run(Dummy x) {
        out.println("Hello world")
    }
}
class X ext ProxifiedObject {
    PrintHelloThread thread
    void main(X x) {
        x.thread := new PrintHelloThread;
        x.thread.start(0);
        x.thread.join(0);
    }
}
\end{lstlisting}}
&
{\begin{lstlisting}[
basicstyle={\scriptsize\ttfamily},
identifierstyle={\color{black}},
tabsize=2,
language={Java},
numbersep=16pt,
numbers=left,
xleftmargin=1cm,frame=tlbr,framesep=2pt,framerule=0pt,
morekeywords ={class,run}
]
class PrintHelloThread ext Thread {
    void run(Dummy x) {
        out.println("Hello world")
    }
}
class X ext ProxifiedObject {
    PrintHelloThread thread
    void main(X x) {
        x.thread := new PrintHelloThread;
        x.thread.start(0);
        x.thread.join(0);
    }
}
\end{lstlisting}}
\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{adjustwidth}
\caption{\label{fig:text}text experiment ent experiment experiment}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the symbols defined in `pifont` package (see page 77, Table 254 of [The Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf)).

Adding the option `mathescape=true` to your `listing` environment you can write something like

```
$\llap{\textrm{\ding{173}}}$
```

at the beginning of the line where you want that symbol.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[english,a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pifont}

\begin{document}

\clearpage
\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{adjustwidth}{-3.7cm}{}
\begin{tabular}{|p{.6\textwidth}|p{.75\textwidth}|}
\hline
{\begin{lstlisting}[mathescape=true,
basicstyle={\scriptsize\ttfamily},
identifierstyle={\color{black}},
tabsize=2,language={Java},
numbersep=18pt,numbers=left,xleftmargin=1.2cm,frame=tlbr,framesep=2pt,framerule=0pt,
morekeywords={class,run}]
class PrintHelloThread ext Thread {
    void run(Dummy x) {
        out.println("Hello world")
    }
}
class X ext ProxifiedObject {
    PrintHelloThread thread
    void main(X x) {
        x.thread := new PrintHelloThread;
        x.thread.start(0);
        x.thread.join(0);
    }
}
\end{lstlisting}}
&
{\begin{lstlisting}[mathescape=true,
basicstyle={\scriptsize\ttfamily},
identifierstyle={\color{black}},
tabsize=2,
language={Java},
numbersep=16pt,
numbers=left,
xleftmargin=1cm,frame=tlbr,framesep=2pt,framerule=0pt,
morekeywords ={class,run}
]
class PrintHelloThread ext Thread {
    void run(Dummy x) {
        out.println("Hello world")
    }
}
class X ext ProxifiedObject {
    PrintHelloThread thread
$\llap{\textrm{\ding{173}}}$    void main(X x) {
        x.thread := new PrintHelloThread;
        x.thread.start(0);
$\llap{\textrm{\ding{173}}}$        x.thread.join(0);
    }
}
\end{lstlisting}}
\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{adjustwidth}
\caption{\label{fig:text}text experiment ent experiment experiment}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I also look at page 79, table:261 making a filled circle with this command: '$\llap{$\FilledSmallSquare}$' but it does not work. What should I do in order to use that?

Comment: @Hakan `\usepackage[geometry]{ifsym}` in the preamble and then `$\llap{\textrm{\FilledSmallSquare}}$`

Answer (score 2):

Another option with `tikz`. The technique used is similar to that of Karl, but I used `escapechar` key.

```
escapechar=|,
```

And the numbers are put as a `node` with `overlay` option so as to not disturb other things.

Code:

```
\documentclass[english,a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{mynode/.style={draw=blue,circle,inner sep=1pt,font=\tiny,anchor=south}
}

\begin{document}

\clearpage
\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{adjustwidth}{-3.7cm}{}
\begin{tabular}{|p{.6\textwidth}|p{.75\textwidth}|}
\hline
{\begin{lstlisting}[escapechar=|,
basicstyle={\scriptsize\ttfamily},
identifierstyle={\color{black}},
tabsize=2,language={Java},
numbersep=18pt,numbers=left,xleftmargin=1.2cm,frame=tlbr,framesep=2pt,framerule=0pt,
morekeywords={class,run}]
class PrintHelloThread ext Thread {
    void run(Dummy x) {
        out.println("Hello world")
    }
}
class X ext ProxifiedObject {
    PrintHelloThread thread
    void main(X x) {
        x.thread := new PrintHelloThread;
        x.thread.start(0);
        x.thread.join(0);
    }
}
\end{lstlisting}}
&
{\begin{lstlisting}[escapechar=|,
basicstyle={\scriptsize\ttfamily},
identifierstyle={\color{black}},
tabsize=2,
language={Java},
numbersep=16pt,
numbers=left,
xleftmargin=1cm,frame=tlbr,framesep=2pt,framerule=0pt,
morekeywords ={class,run}
]
class PrintHelloThread ext Thread {
    void run(Dummy x) {
        out.println("Hello world")
    }
}
class X ext ProxifiedObject {
    PrintHelloThread thread
|\tikz[overlay]\node[mynode,fill=orange,yshift=-0.8ex]{1};|    void main(X x) {
        x.thread := new PrintHelloThread;
        x.thread.start(0);
|\tikz[overlay]\node[mynode,fill=violet,yshift=-1ex]{173};|        x.thread.join(0);
    }
}
\end{lstlisting}}
\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{adjustwidth}
\caption{\label{fig:text}text experiment ent experiment experiment}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Along comes the benefits of `tikz` like filling, drawing etc to make the circle more beautiful.